# Datetime number of days difference group by months

Tags: python, datetime, group-by

I want to find the days between two dates, but grouped by months.

Example:

```
start = datetime(2020,10,1)
end = datetime(2020,12,15)

end - start

> datetime.timedelta(days=75)
```

I want these 75 days grouped by months:

- 30 days in October
- 30 days in November
- 15 days in December

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `itertools.groupby` to get number of days in each month:

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

start = datetime(2020,10,1)
end = datetime(2020,12,15)

for v, g in groupby(((start + timedelta(days=i)).month for i in range(1, (end - start).days + 1))):
    l = sum(1 for _ in g)
    print('{} {} in {}'.format(l, 'day' if l == 1 else 'days', calendar.month_name[v]))
```

Prints:

```
30 days in October
30 days in November
15 days in December
```