# Datetime number of days difference group by months and years

Tags: python, date, datetime, group-by, python-itertools

I want to find the days between two dates, but grouped by months and years.

Referring to [Datetime number of days difference group by months](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59991491/datetime-number-of-days-difference-group-by-months)

```
import calendar
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

start = datetime(2020,12,30) 
end = datetime(2021,12,15)
```

if the start year and end year is different, and i need the result group by month and year. How could i apply the code to get the answer?

Thank you so mucd

Comment: Get diff of datatimes, then create list of dates(based on start and diff), then start grouping dates by your requests, and you will get result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on the idea shared in the other answer, you create a list of dates, `map` them to the group you want, and then count using `groupby`

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from itertools import groupby

start = datetime(2020,12,30) 
end = datetime(2021,12,15) 

dates = (start + timedelta(days=i) for i in range(1, (end - start).days + 1))
year_months = map(lambda x: (x.year, x.month), dates)

for v, g in groupby(year_months):
    print(v, sum(1 for _ in g))


Output:
(2020, 12) 1
(2021, 1) 31
(2021, 2) 28
(2021, 3) 31
(2021, 4) 30
(2021, 5) 31
(2021, 6) 30
(2021, 7) 31
(2021, 8) 31
(2021, 9) 30
(2021, 10) 31
(2021, 11) 30
(2021, 12) 15
```

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for the answer and also it worked very well. But I wonder if my data has around one million rows and I need to for loop each row to do your answer, if it would take a long time or not?